# NavLink to display default component in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
            <div className="menubutton">
              <NavLink exact to="/assigned"><button>Assigned</button></NavLink>
              <NavLink to="/picked"><button>Picked</button></NavLink>
              <NavLink to="/completed"><button>Completed</button></NavLink>
            </div>
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path='/assigned' component={ () =><AssignedComponent  />} />
              <Route exact path='/picked' component={PickingComponent} />
              <Route exact path='/completed' component={CompletedComponent} />
            </Switch>
          </div>

      </BrowserRouter>
```

How  to display assigned component on page enters.I am getting after clicking the assigned button.But I need on page enters Please Help me out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `Redirect` at the end to redirect to `'/assigned'`

```
  </BrowserRouter>
      <div className="menubutton">
          <NavLink exact to="/assigned"><button>Assigned</button></NavLink>
          <NavLink to="/picked"><button>Picked</button></NavLink>
          <NavLink to="/completed"><button>Completed</button></NavLink>
        </div>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path='/assigned' component={ () =><AssignedComponent  />} />
          <Route exact path='/picked' component={PickingComponent} />
          <Route exact path='/completed' component={CompletedComponent} />
          <Redirect to"/assigned" />
        </Switch>
      </div>

  </BrowserRouter>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put the a default route as the last item in the Switch:

```
<Switch>
  <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>

  <Route path="/users" component={Users}/>
  <Redirect from="/accounts" to="/users"/>

  <Route component={NoMatch}/>
</Switch>
```

(from https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Switch/Switch-props)

So in your case the last item in the switch would be:

```
<Route component={AssignedComponent} />
```